# Why I cannot print the character "\" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I use `print()` function to use like this:`print("\")`and i get an exception. Tell me how to slove it. Thks

Comment: Backslash is an escape character, so if you want a literal backslash just escape it: "\\". Otherwise your string is not a complete string: the second " is interpreted as being *part of the string* (and everything after it like the close paren is as well) rather than the delimiter. Which is why you get the error, you have an unterminated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\\` instead.

Actually, `\` is a special character and you have to escape it.

```
print("\\") # print a single "\" character
```